Prisma ORM how to order by GREATEST()
I have a database table with two columns updated_at and children_updated_at and I would like to show the latest modified records first based on the SQL function GREATEST(updated_at, children_updated_at). I want to achieve this using Prisma ORM.
The SQL query I'd like to generate is:
select * from Account ORDER BY GREATEST(updated_at, children_updated_at);

The output should be ordered by the highest value of updated_at and children_updated_at.
To be clear: this is different from first ordering by updated_at and then by children_updated_at, which is easily done using Prisma.
An input table like this:



name
updated_at
children_updated_at




User 1
2024-05-07 10:00:00.000
2024-05-07 13:00:00.000


User 2
2024-05-07 11:00:00.000
2024-05-07 09:00:00.000


User 3
2024-05-07 12:00:00.000
2024-05-07 10:00:00.000



Should generate an output like this:
[
  { "name": "User 1",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-07 10:00:00.000",
    "children_updated_at": "2024-05-07 13:00:00.000"
  },
  { "name": "User 3",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-07 12:00:00.000",
    "children_updated_at": "2024-05-07 10:00:00.000"
  },
  { "name": "User 2",
    "updated_at": "2024-05-07 11:00:00.000",
    "children_updated_at": "2024-05-07 09:00:00.000"
  }
]

I could not find anything about using GREATEST() or other SQL functions that combine columns in the Prisma documentation.
The actual query is a lot more complex, and because of that a raw sql query will not work for me.
Is there a way to achieve this requirement using Prisma ORM?

Share some sample input & output file @HendrikJan

I've added sample input table and output json.

Prisma does not directly support using functions like GREATEST. However, you can achieve similar functionality by using a combination of Prisma's .orderBy() method wit js
const accounts = await prisma.account.findMany({
  orderBy: {
    updatedAt: 'desc', 
    childrenUpdatedAt: 'desc',
  },
});


const result = accounts.map(account => ({
  name: account.name,
  updated_at: account.updatedAt.toISOString(), // Convert to ISO string
  children_updated_at: account.childrenUpdatedAt.toISOString(), // Convert to ISO string
}));

console.log(result);

This example will fetch the records from the database ordered first by updatedAt in descending order, and then by childrenUpdatedAt in descending order.
Hope this works for you...

Thank you for this answer. I think this will not work the way I want it. Your answer will first order by updatedAt and only if two updatedAt's are the same it will order by childrenUpdatedAt.
What I am looking for is to order by the greatest of the two, which will not be achieved in this way.

I've slightly updated my question to make this requirement clearer.

First create a indicator column and do order by on that column
MySQL query:
select *
from inputTable
order by GREATEST(COALESCE(updated_at, 0), COALESCE(children_updated_at, 0)) desc

or
With T as(
  select *,
  GREATEST(updated_at, children_updated_at) as order_by
from inputTable
)
select name, updated_at, children_updated_at
from T
order by order_by desc

or
select name, updated_at, children_updated_at
from (
  select *,
  GREATEST(updated_at, children_updated_at) as order_by
  from inputTable
) T
order by order_by desc

View Result: db<>fiddle
Output:

GREATEST(dt1, dt2) Will work. But if any date is null, then it will not work.
So, better use GREATEST(COALESCE(dt1, 0), COALESCE(dt2, 0))

Thank you for this SQL solution. What I asked for is a Prisma ORM solution, but I might not have been clear enough about that in my question. I've edited my question a bit to make that clearer.
Prisma seems not to support GREATEST() so the normal SQL way will not work for me.
